# Screen class doesn't get recognized by Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2017 when I try using the screen class:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Screen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to the assembly `System.Windows.Forms` in your project?

Comment: Works for me !!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is you are in a console app, and calling a winforms library.

[Screen.AllScreens Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets an array of all displays on the system.
>
> - **Namespace**:   System.Windows.Forms
> - **Assembly**:  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

The above is very important

When you have a problem like this, try and look on line for the documentation

What is says, is you need to add the assembly `System.Windows.Forms` to your application.

[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

> To add a reference in Visual C#
>
> - In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.
> - In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
> - Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` library.

1. Go to the `Project` menu
2. Select `Add reference`
3. Click on `Assemblies` (on the left)
4. Check `System.Windows.Forms`
5. Click OK

Of course this will only work with a .NET Framework project, so if yours isn't it won't work (`System.Windows.Forms` won't work).